# Change page inside a frame from another frame

Tags: c#, frame, silverlight-5.0

In my MainPage I have 3 frames,and trying to change the page of my FrameMain(frame) to another page,the problem is that I am doing this in another page inside a second frame if I use

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/View/CreateAcc.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

It loads my current frame with the page,but I want the FrameMain to load this page, so I tried:

```
MainPage main = new MainPage();
main.FrameMain.Navigate(new Uri("/View/CreateAcc.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

wich didn't do anything...
sorry about the confuse text if someone can help i only saw examples of changing pages inside the MainPage.

Comment: Are you using prism or mvvm?

Comment: I am not using any simply using a normal silverlight project haven't started to implement mvvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the way of doing to get what i wanted,instead of using frame implemented two WrapPanel at exactly the same position and used the property Visibility to put one Visible and the other Collapsed and vice verse to change Panel showing.